# Mapping a position within a QHeaderView to the context of the scrolled Viewport

Tags: qt, widget, qtableview, qheaderview

I have a QHeaderView that does a few things when clicking either to the left or right of the center of a section header.

For this, I need to know the position of the click in relation to the (possibly scrolled) content of the QHeaderView's **viewport**.
The actual click position, however, refers only to the QHeaderView (which is always fixed).

I tried variants of mapTo/From, but can't find the correct way to do it.
Here's simplified code:

```
void MyTableHeader::headerSectionClicked(int section_index, int click_pos)
{
    int section_size = sectionSize(0); // All sections in a header are equally sized
    int section_center = (section_size * (section_index+ 1)) - (section_size / 2); // Center of the clicked section

    if (section_index>= 0)// if mouse is over an item
    {
        if (orientation() == Qt::Horizontal)
        {
            QPoint x_pos = QPoint(click_pos, 0);
            int mapped_offset = viewport()->mapFrom(this, x_pos).x();

            if (mapped_offset != -1)
            {
                // If the click was to the right of the center, iterate on the index
                if (mapped_offset >= section_center)
                {
                    section_index++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Same thing for the Y-dimension
        }
    }

    // Neat stuff after this
}
```

The part where the problem occurs, is where I want to find out on which side of the section the click happened.

```
// If the click was to the right of the center, iterate on the index
if (mapped_offset >= section_center)
{
    in_index++;
}
```

This **mapped_offset** does not properly refer to the same context as the section center.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution might give you an idea on what to do.

**MyHeaderView.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QHeaderView>

class MyHeaderView : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyHeaderView(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
};
```

**MyHeaderView.cpp**

```
#include "MyHeaderView.h"
#include <QDebug>

MyHeaderView::MyHeaderView(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget* parent) : QHeaderView(orientation, parent)
{
    setSectionsClickable(true);
    connect(this, &MyHeaderView::sectionClicked, [this](int section)
        {
            QRect currentSectionRect;
            currentSectionRect.setRect(sectionViewportPosition(section), 0, sectionSize(section), viewport()->height());
            auto pos = QCursor::pos();
            auto localPos = mapFromGlobal(pos);

            qDebug() << currentSectionRect << localPos;
            qDebug() << currentSectionRect.contains(localPos); //"Always true!"
        });
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyHeaderView.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto model = new QStandardItemModel;
    auto view = new QTableView;
    view->setModel(model);
    model->setRowCount(4);
    model->setColumnCount(4);
    view->setHorizontalHeader(new MyHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal));
    view->show();
    app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I think this might work, but not in my specific case. Because I can't use the "sectionClicked"-signal, and so the QCursor::pos() contains invalid values at the time a section click is registered in my case. Thanks nonetheless!